# How can I resume/save work in a to-be-killed VNC session

Tags: linux, vnc

I run VNC server at CentOS 6.4 and VNC client at windows machine. For some reason, VNC is not working properly today; there is no response of normal key presses, some mouse clicks work (changing workspaces, select terminal), but closing applications using the mouse do not work.

The only solution I know is to start another VNC server, but the problem is, I have quite a bit of some GUI windows open and they are not saved yet. If I start another VNC session, my work in the previous session is lost.

Is there a way the new VNC session can inherit/clone another VNC session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try invoking `x11vnc` (this would be in addition to the VNC server already running that your attempting to connect to). This would provide a 2nd VNC server instance that is bound to the same desktop. With this running you could then attempt to connect to this second VNC server that's providing access to the same display that the VNC server above is also displaying.

#### Example

```
$ x11vnc -display :0 -nopw
```

Doing the above should return an additional VNC port that you can now connect on:

```
$ x11vnc -display :0 -nopw
22/01/2014 14:39:37 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 28625
22/01/2014 14:39:37 Using X display :0
22/01/2014 14:39:37 rootwin: 0x86 reswin: 0x6200001 dpy: 0x1f3ce80
22/01/2014 14:39:37 
...
22/01/2014 14:39:37 fb read rate: 61 MB/sec
22/01/2014 14:39:37 The X server says there are 24 mouse buttons.
22/01/2014 14:39:37 screen setup finished.
22/01/2014 14:39:37 

The VNC desktop is:      greeneggs.bubba.net:0
PORT=5900
...
```

You should now be able to connect to the host on VNC port 5900, which equates to display :0. If you need to override the VNC port for whatever reason consult the help for `x11vnc`. There are switches for controlling various aspects to VNC ports etc.

```
$ x11vnc --help
```

Comment: thanks...I do not have right to install software on that Linux machine, is there an alternative?

Comment: @my_question - is this software not already installed?

Comment: no, the centos machine does not have x11vnc installed. The VNC-not-responsive problem is gone, so I am not blocked now, thanks for the suggestion.